# How to apply header and footer or layout to all pages in a panel enabled website?

Tags: 7, theming

I have decided to use the `Panels` module and the `Precision` theme to implement my website. I have designed a front page (using a Panel page) and it has a nice header and footer.

I have also created a user for testing purposes, but when I click on the link in the email to reset the password, I get something like this:

[image]

I have some editors (i.e., with a specific user profile) who must be able to create node instances (i.e., tip articles), but without proper layout for standard Drupal pages, the screens are ugly and not functional.

The `Precision` theme does not come with much CSS and layout. How can I implement some minimum layout on all standard Drupal pages and eventually move the header and footer to those pages too? The header and footer are implemented as mini-panels.

I am still new to Drupal. What is the proper strategy here? Thanks.

Comment: JVerstry,  You appear to be asking two questions here.  It would be less confusing if you remove the user issue and ask it as a separate question.

Comment: I agree I am a bit confused about all layout related concepts in Drupal. I have asked another question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22553/panels-mini-panels-vs-block-regions-vs-display-suite-vs-stylizer-vs-page-manager. I hope it will help me clarify this one.

Comment: JVerstry,  I asked you to write another question, but they closed it while I was writing an answer.  I have posted the content on a tag wiki "Drupal Concepts" which I have added to your question tags.  It must be approved (probably later today) before you can see it.  To find it click on the tag in your question and select 'info' from the pop-up.

Comment: @Ashlar: Many thanks, it will really help !!! I have been struggling days with these..

Comment: Three solid resources to study are Definitive Guide to Drupal 7, Drupal 7 Development and Drupal Building Blocks.  Also, Dev.nodeone.se has excellent videos on some of the Contributed modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if Precision has standard regions.  IF it has headers and footers, you should be able to access the regions in the admin/structure/blocks page and place your mini panels where you want.  If you have chosen Precision because it is minimalist, then you might want to consider adding the 'Panels Everywhere' module.  This module works very well with Panels (same authors) and allows you to bypass the Drupal Theming process altogether.  This greatly simplified my styling work.  Ctools also has a module "Stylizer" which can help defining styles (although it has some limitations in terms of what it can do at the present).

Comment: Bottom line is that I need to get even deeper into the page manager and related concepts first. I have installed Panels everywhere too.

Comment: Precision does have standard regions, I can access them in Home > Administration > Structure > Blocks. And, when integrating with Panels Everywhere, one can (should) set a site template where my headers and footers can be set.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of answers to your question. Here is mine :)

I usually define 3 areas. The Header and the Footer are "static" blocks that are shown in every site pages. The content is in the middle and is defined with Pages and Panels. That's it!

Comment: Yes, but that is not an answer to my question. How do you get to have your 'static block' displayed on all pages with the Precision theme?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really know that theme, but any standard Drupal theme allows you to do this.

In Administration > Structure > Blocks you can create blocks and enable them for Header and Footer regions.